# reactjs google-distance-matrix updating component

Tags: reactjs, scope, state, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I am super new to reactjs an am pretty junior.

I am playing around the google distance matrix api.  user inputs origin and destination on the form and the event handler passes the values into the matrix function but within the function it cannot update the state variables.

Any thoughts?

```
import React from 'react';  
import GoogleMap from 'google-distance-matrix';
class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        address: '', 
        dest:'', 
        distanceText:'testing the distance text' 
    }
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);

    this.onChange = (address) => this.setState({ address });
    this.changeDest = (dest) => this.setState({dest});
}
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()        
    GoogleMap.matrix(this.state.address, this.state.dest, function (err, distances) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if(!distances) {
            return console.log('no distances');
        }
        if (distances.status == 'OK') {
            if(distances.rows[0].elements[0])  {
                var distance = distances.rows[0].elements[0].duration['text'];
                this.setState({
                    foundDistance: true, 
                    distanceText: distance

                }); 
            }
        } 
    });

}
```

Comment: Well "this" in GoogleMap.matrix does not point to the "this" of the SimpleForm component. Try to use .bind(this) at the end of the matrix function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding has more of a performance hit, however slight, than simply caching `this` in a variable (which is a pretty standard pattern).

Also, use destructuring on `this.state`.

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    const component = this
    const { address, dest } = this.state

    event.preventDefault()        

    GoogleMap.matrix(address, dest, function (err, distances) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        if(!distances) {
            return console.log('no distances');
        }

        if (distances.status == 'OK') {
            if(distances.rows[0].elements[0])  {
                var distance = distances.rows[0].elements[0].duration['text'];

                component.setState({
                    foundDistance: true, 
                    distanceText: distance
                }); 
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" in GoogleMap.matrix does not point to the "this" of the SimpleForm component. Bind it:

```
...
GoogleMap.matrix(...)
...
).bind(this)
```